# Does $f(x)=\frac1x\int_0^x\frac{1}{\sin t+\sin (\pi t)+2}dt$ have a supremum?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, definite-integrals, supremum-and-infimum, average

Does $f(x)=\frac1x\int_0^x\frac{1}{\sin t+\sin (\pi t)+2}dt$ have a supremum?

(This question was inspired by [What is the mean value of $|\sin x +\sin (\pi x)|$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4737402/398708).)

**My thoughts:**

$\frac{1}{\sin t+\sin (\pi t)+2}$ can be arbitrarily large, but that doesn't tell me whether its average value from $t=0$ to $t=x$, for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, has a supremum.

Wolfram [does not evaluate](https://%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csin%20t+%5Csin%20(%5Cpi%20t)+2%7Ddt) $\int \frac{1}{\sin t+\sin (\pi t)+2}dt$.

Here is the graph of $y=\frac1x\int_0^x\frac{1}{\sin t+\sin (\pi t)+2}dt$ from $x=-30$ to $x=30$.

[image]

Comment: I believe this is an open problem. If $f(x)$ does have a supremum, it should imply the [irrational measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Irrationality_measure) of $\pi$, let's call it $\mu$, is $2$. As of this moment, no one know what the exact value of $\mu$ is, we only know $2 \le \mu \le 7.1032..$ ([ref](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.06345))

Comment: Why did you remove your last question about $\sup(\frac{\tan n}n)$?

Comment: @MichaelMorad It was answered by [Concerning the sequence $\Big(\dfrac {\tan n}{n}\Big) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/686841/398708).